# Problem with radio froup if not selected

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio button in with name `gender`. I am getting values of radios using jquery.

```
<label id="msg"></label>    
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</label>
```

Related Jquery.

```
var gender = $('input[name=gender]:checked','#addchildform').val();
if (gender === null || gender === "") {
        $('#msg').html("<h3>Select Gender.</h3>");
        return false;
}
```

My Issue is though I am getting value of selected radio but I if value is "" or null. I am not getting error message in label with id msg.

Comment: why you want to get error then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input[name=gender]:checked','#addchildform').val()` should return `undefined` if the radio is not checked.
Alter your code like that and give it a try:

```
if (typeof gender === 'undefined') {
        $('#msg').html("<h3>Select Gender.</h3>");
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Better: `if (typeof gender === 'undefined')`

Answer (score 0):

In this sample I get `undefined`. Here is woring solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ypa59/2/